# Aguardar Thread terminar para prosseguir com o código - Delphi

Tags: delphi, thread

Estou enfrentando um problema em uma aplicação na qual desenvolvi. 
É um atualizador automático que basicamente faz download dos arquivos necessários e extrai num caminho adequado. 
O problema está na hora de efetuar o download. Eu coloquei o método de download dentro de uma Thread, coloquei dentro do Syncronize, porém ele "trava", não deixa eu mexer a janela(interface) até acabar o processo. Lembrando que ao baixar ele chama o método que altera a barra de progresso.

Em um outro caso, eu coloco somente o método que altera a barra de carregamento dentro do syncronize, fazendo com que a janela não fique mais travada, eu consigo mexer ela enquanto o download é feito, porém todo o restante do código é executado e isso não pode acontecer no meu caso, porque eu dependo do arquivo que está sendo baixado para continuar.

A dúvida final é, como faço para esperar esse download terminar, essa Thread concluir, antes de prosseguir com a execução do código? Porque se eu prosseguir vai dar erro na aplicação pelo fato de não ter o arquivo, pois o mesmo ainda está sendo baixado.

**Chamada do método de download dentro do Formulario principal** **(uFrmPrincipal.pas)**

```
ThreadBaixarAtualização('c:\caminho\atua_beta',
  'http://www.site.com.br/atualizacao/atua_beta.zip', true);

ThreadBaixarAtualização('c:\caminho\scripts',
    'http://www.site.com.br/atualizacao/scripts.zip', False);
```

**Método para criar a instância da Thread dentro do Formulario principal (uFrmPrincipal.pas)**

```
procedure TfrmAtualizador.ThreadBaixarAtualização(CaminhoNomeArquivo,
    URL: String; Status: Boolean);
  begin
    FConHTTPThread := TConHTTPThread.create(true, UpdateProgressBar);
    FConHTTPThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
    FConHTTPThread.URL := URL;
    FConHTTPThread.CaminhoNomeArquivo := CaminhoNomeArquivo;
    FConHTTPThread.Status := Status;
    FConHTTPThread.Start;
  end;
```

**Método que altera a barra de progresso no formulário principal (uFrmPrincipal.pas)**

```
  procedure TfrmAtualizador.UpdateProgressBar(aProgress, Total: Int64);
  begin
    gProgresso.MaxValue := Total;
    gProgresso.Progress := aProgress;
    gProgresso.Update;
  end;
```

**Classe(Unit) para fazer o download dos arquivos - Unit separada(uConHTTPThread.pas)**

```
  unit uConHTTPThread;

  interface

  uses
    System.Classes, SysUtils, Forms, IdHTTP, IdComponent,
    Vcl.Dialogs, System.UITypes;

  type
    // Tipo que contem um método com os mesmos parâmetros que a barra de progresso
    // do formulario principal
    TBarraProgress = procedure(aProgress, Total: Int64) of object;

    TConHTTPThread = class(TThread)
      procedure IdHTTP1Work(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
        AWorkCount: Int64);
      procedure IdHTTP1WorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
        AWorkCountMax: Int64);
      procedure IdHTTP1WorkEnd(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
    private
      FIdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
      FValorMaximo: Int64;
      FProgresso: Int64;
      FfileDownload: TFileStream;
      FCaminhoNomeArquivo, FURL: String;
      FStatus: Boolean;
      FBarraProgress: TBarraProgress;
      procedure SetCaminhoNomeArquivo(const Value: String);
      procedure SetURL(const Value: String);
      procedure SetStatus(const Value: Boolean);
      procedure AtualizaBarra;
    protected
      procedure Execute; override;
      procedure BaixarAtualizacao;
      procedure Progress(aProgress: Int64); virtual;
    Public
      property Progresso: Int64 read FProgresso;
      property Total: Int64 read FValorMaximo;
      property CaminhoNomeArquivo: String read FCaminhoNomeArquivo
        write SetCaminhoNomeArquivo;
      property URL: String read FURL write SetURL;
      property Status: Boolean read FStatus write SetStatus;

      constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean;
        pBarraProgress: TBarraProgress); reintroduce; virtual;
    end;

  implementation

  // Responsável por efetuar o Donwload dos arquivos de atualização
  procedure TConHTTPThread.BaixarAtualizacao;
  begin
    try
      if not Assigned(FIdHTTP1) then
        FIdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(Nil);

      FfileDownload := TFileStream.Create(FCaminhoNomeArquivo +
        ExtractFileExt(FURL), fmCreate);

      if Status = True then
      begin
        with FIdHTTP1 do
        begin
          OnWork := IdHTTP1Work;
          OnWorkBegin := IdHTTP1WorkBegin;
        end;
      end;
      FIdHTTP1.Get(FURL, FfileDownload);
    finally
      if Assigned(FIdHTTP1) then
        FreeAndNil(FIdHTTP1);
      if Assigned(FfileDownload) then
        FreeAndNil(FfileDownload);
    end;
  end;

  constructor TConHTTPThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean;
    pBarraProgress: TBarraProgress);
  begin
    inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
    FBarraProgress := pBarraProgress;
  end;

  procedure TConHTTPThread.Execute;
  begin
    if (not Terminated) then
    begin
      Sleep(10);
      Synchronize(BaixarAtualizacao);
    end;
  end;

  procedure TConHTTPThread.IdHTTP1Work(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
    AWorkCount: Int64);
  begin
    Progress(AWorkCount);
  end;

  procedure TConHTTPThread.IdHTTP1WorkBegin(ASender: TObject;
    AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCountMax: Int64);
  begin
    // Verifica tamanho total do arquivo a ser baixado
    FValorMaximo := AWorkCountMax;
  end;

  procedure TConHTTPThread.IdHTTP1WorkEnd(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
  begin
    FValorMaximo := FValorMaximo;
  end;

  procedure TConHTTPThread.Progress(aProgress: Int64);
  begin
    FProgresso := aProgress;
    AtualizaBarra;
  end;

  procedure TConHTTPThread.SetCaminhoNomeArquivo(const Value: String);
  begin
    FCaminhoNomeArquivo := Value;
  end;

  procedure TConHTTPThread.SetStatus(const Value: Boolean);
  begin
    FStatus := Value;
  end;

  procedure TConHTTPThread.SetURL(const Value: String);
  begin
    FURL := Value;
  end;

  procedure TConHTTPThread.AtualizaBarra;
  begin
    // Atualiza barra de progresso no formulário principal
    if Assigned(FBarraProgress) then
      FBarraProgress(FProgresso, FValorMaximo);
  end;

  end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você utilizar o Synchronize ali dentro do Execute da thread, quem vai realizar o trabalho de executar o bloco de código "BaixarAtualizacao" será a thread principal, ou seja, nesse seu caso você meio que "matou" o uso da thread e fez o seu programa executar o processo de download sem ela.

Para sua necessidade, você pode implementar um método que seja executado ao finalizar a thread, e seta ele no OnTerminate da thread quando for cria-la, segue um simples exemplo que fiz, quando a thread finalizar, irá executar o bloco de código que está dentro do FinalizarThread.

```
TTeste = class(TThread)
public
    procedure Execute;
    procedure FinalizarThread(Sender: TObject);

    constructor Create;
end;

implementation 

{$R *.dfm}

{ TTeste }

constructor TTeste.Create;
begin
    OnTerminate :=FinalizarThread;
end

procedure TTeste.Execute;
begin
    ////Executa o processo de download
end;

procedure TTeste.FinalizarThread(Sender: TObject);
begin
    //Processo a realizar após finalizar a thread
end;
```

Comment: Entendi. Vou trabalhar em cima dessa ideia. Obrigado.

Comment: Certo, qualquer coisa estou a disposição.

Answer (score 0):

Assim como você tem uma procedure chamada `IdHTTP1WorkBegin`, você pode desenvolver uma `IdHTTP1WorkEnd`, sendo que na procedure `IdHTTP1WorkBegin` você pode colocar algumas funcionalidades (Controles como botões e etc) com o `Enabled = False` e no `IdHTTP1WorkEnd` reabilitar esses controles desabilitados.

O objetivo da thread é justamente não precisar a MainThread aguardar a finalização do processo secundário, então o que pode ser feito é um controle auxiliar como o sugerido acima.

Comment: Beleza. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

O correto é mesmo usar o Syncronize apenas para atualizar a interface gráfica (não para fazer o download).
Eu já fiz algo parecido utilizando o evento OnTerminate da Thread:
Em uma variável armazenava a quantidade total de threads e no handler do OnTerminate decrementava a variável.
Ao chegar a zero, prosseguia o processamento.

Comment: Entendi! Obrigado.